# Swift 3 NSArray compare to nil

Tags: swift, xcode, variables

I'm trying to migrate an objc project to swift3. I'm not sure how can I compare an array to nil. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686948/how-to-check-object-is-nil-or-not-in-swift) topic, but that was 2 years ago and the swift's syntax has changed a lot.

If I have a code like this in swift:

```
let variable = something as? NSArray
  if variable == nil {
    // do something
  }
```

It won't let me to compare this variable with nil, causing an error "comparing this variable, always returns false". I have tried comparing variable.description with " ", but does it do the same thing?
By "something" i meant:

```
var variable = dict.object(forKey: someString) as! NSArray
```

The main thing I wanted to do with this was:

```
var variable = dict.object(forKey: someString) as! NSArray
  if variable == nil {
    //create 
  }
  else {
    // append
  }
```

Comment: Can you also show us how you've defined `something` please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an optional value in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: Basically don't use `NSArray` in Swift. You are throwing away the type information. Use always Swift `Array`.

Comment: You might want to be able to use your `variable` outside of this `if` block sometime later, right?

Comment: @Vadian so it means that always should use Array, String, Date etc instead of NSArray, NSString, NSDate?

Comment: @Mr.Mioio Yes, exactly

Answer (score 3):

That's what the optional unwrapping syntax is for. You can combine the unwrapping and cast into one if statement:

```
if let variable = something as? NSArray {
    // variable is not nil and is an NSArray
    // Now you can do something with it.
} else {
    // Either something is nil or it is not able to be cast as an NSArray
    // Handle this case.
}
```

I should also mention that if you don't need to use `something` in Objective-C, then you should use the Swift-native array type. This can be declared like this:

```
let someArray = ["string1", "string2"]
```

Comment: I don't remember and cant check it right now. But it was something with object forkey, if I'm right. I will try this tomorrow.And one more thing, I can just type else statement if "variable" is nil?

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: by "something" i meant this -> var variable = dict.object(forKey: someString) as! NSArray. Does it changes something or I still can use your example?

Answer (score 1):

This line indicates that variable **is** and **must be** an NSArray. If `dict.object(forKey: someString)` is not an NSArray, this will cause a crash

```
var variable = dict.object(forKey: someString) as! NSArray
//                                               ^
// This exclamation mark means you are certain this is an NSArray
// Also, because there is no question mark after NSArray, this variable
// is not optional. It cannot be nil
```

However, you then use

```
if variable == nil {
```

And this is where the warning comes from. The variable can never be nil, because the variable is not **`optional`**

---

What you probably want is:

```
if let variable = dict.object(forKey:someString) as? NSArray
```

This will return false if:

- `dict.object(forKey:someString)` returns a nil object
- the object returned is not an NSArray

After this `variable` is now a **non-optional** NSArray. It is guaranteed to be an NSArray and is guaranteed to not be `nil`. You can use it without *unwrapping* it. e.g.

```
if let variable = dict.object(forKey:someString) as? NSArray {
    for element in variable {
    }
}
else {
    //The dict doesn't contain the object yet. `variable` is nil
    //Create a new array and add it to dict
    let newArray = ["First Value"]
    dict[someString] = newArray
}
```

Comment: But by the first, I need it to be a nil. Cause first time it creates the list and the all other times it just appends the array.

Comment: Then you just need an else clause. Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let variable = something as? NSArray
```

With this declaration, `variable` will be an optional type (`NSArray?`) and never nil. This is because casting with `as?` returns an optional value that either contains the successfully casted object or nothing. You can see this by <kbd>alt</kbd>-clicking the variable name in Xcode.

If you want to know whether it contains a value, you need to use the `if let` syntax:

```
if let variable = variable {
    // variable is guaranteed to be an NSArray here.
}
```

Comment: Isn't `nil` a literal value that the compiler translates into `Optional.none` ? AFAIK, you can always compare an Optional to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this format with `guard-else`:

```
guard let variable = something as? NSArray else {
    // your variable is nil. Do something if needed
}
// your variable is available in this scope. Do something when variable contains Array
```